# How to bring points in a tikz grid closer together/remove the space between points in grid in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, grids

So I have a grid of 4x19 points/small circles, which need to be individually colored later. It has to fit into a beamer presentation sheet, so the points have to be brought closer together.

This is what I have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18}
\foreach \y in {0,1,2,3}
{
\draw (\x,\y) circle (0.1cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: This is the grid it generates, with in the right the cutoff point of the beamer sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to change the unit lengths for the x and y coordinates:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18}
    \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3}
    {
        \draw (\x,\y) circle (0.1cm);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can scale the entire `tikzpicture` environment, although this can have other drawbacks as *everything* is scaled. A better way is to scale the coordinates:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

Scale the environment:\medskip

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,18}
      \foreach \y in {0,...,3} { \draw (\x,\y) circle (0.1cm); }
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \bigskip

  Scale the coordinates:\medskip

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,18}
      \foreach \y in {0,...,3} { \draw (0.5*\x,0.5*\y) circle (0.1cm); }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note also that you can abbreviate the csv list that `\foreach` loops over, as in the cases above. You can also loop over non-integer lists using constructions like:

```
\foreach \x in {1,1.5,...,10} {...}
```

With both approaches you can use different scalings in the x and y directions. When scaling the environment you can also use `xscale=...` an `yscale=...` and when scaling the coordinates this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

With beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5,9}
\foreach \y in {0,0.5,1,1.5}
{
\draw (\x,\y) circle (0.1cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]